# JSDoc type of map-like object in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc

Following assignment

```
/**
 * @type {Object<string, string>}
 */
const x = { a: 'b' };
```

IDEA marks with warning

> Initializer type {a: string} is not assignable to variable type Object<string, string>

[image: screenshot of warning in IDEA]

What is the correct way to type-annotate a map-like object so that IDEA can understand it?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Object<string, string>` is a [right way to go](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), and

```
/**
 * @type {Object<string, string>}
 */
const x = { a: "1" };
```

as well as

```
/**
 * @type {Object.<string, string>}
 */
const x = { a: "1" };
```

work fine for me in 2021.2
You can also use the [Google Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) `record` types like

```
*
 * @type {{a: string}}
 */
const y = { a: "1" };
```